# Insanely high RAM usage on Raspberry Pi when starting Script at Start Up but not when starting over Command Line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian, ram, openbox

Sorry if this question has been asked before but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

I'm currently trying to setup a simple Intercom System with TalkKonnect and an OpenBox Environment running Chromium along side it

Launching a custom Python script I wrote and the OpenBox Enviroment is no issue and doesn't even strain the System and when I launch TalkKonnect manually over an SSH Console everything works fine and RAM usage is at around 10-30%.

But when I add the same line of code I used to start TalkKonnect to any launch option at Start-Up, be it rc.local or .bashrc, the RAM and SWAP both fill up to 100% and TalkKonnect gets killed after about 1 minute.

I have been using:

`sudo screen -dmS talkkonnect-radio /root/talkkonnect-run &`

to execute the Script
and the script itself contains:

```
#!/bin/bash 
killall -vs 9 talkkonnect 
sleep 1 
reset 
sleep 2 
/home/talkkonnect/bin/talkkonnect
```

I'm currently rather stuck and don't know of any options that could help

Comment: 1) use systemd instead of cooking up your own  init solution (raspbian ships with systemd, doesn't it?) 2) don't run services with `screen` - requires lots of ram to store screen contents until it can be viewed.  Instead, write the output to a log file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using raspberry pi zero first version then CPU is not sufficient. Use raspberry pi zero 2w or raspberry pi 3 or greater to solve this problem

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow!  While this answer may provide a solution, it doesn't necessarily answer the question that was asked.